# Pass parameter in service to search Rotten Tomato API

Tags: angularjs, json, rotten-tomatoes

I'm trying to create a movie search using Rotten Tomato API but I don't know how to attach the `$scope.nameFilter` as an input to my service. I would like to do something like that:

View

```
<input type="text" ng-model="nameFilter" placeholder="Search..."/>
```

Services

```
     angular.module('MovieFeederApp.services', [])
      .factory('rtAPIservice', function($http, $scope) {

        var rtAPI = {};

        rtAPI.getMoviesAll = function($scope.nameFilter) {
          return $http({
            method: 'JSONP', 
            url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q='+ $scope.nameFilter +  '&page_limit=10&page=1&apikey=MyKey&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
          });
        }
return rtAPI;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function attached to a Controller, which calls the service function passing the parameter.

Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filter" />
<button ng-click="search(filter)">Search Movie</button>
```

CONTROLLER JS:

```
app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope,rtAPIservice ){

  $scope.filter = '';
  $scope.filteredMovies = [];

  $scope.search = function(filter){
    rtAPIservice.getFilteredMovies(filter)
      .then(function(data){
        $scope.filteredMovies = data;
      });
  }

})
```

Factory service

```
app.factory('rtAPIservice', function($http) {

  var rtAPI = {};

  rtAPI.getMoviesAll = function(filter) {
    return $http({
      method: 'JSONP', 
      url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q='+ filter +  '&page_limit=10&page=1&apikey=MyKey&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
      });
    }

  return rtAPI;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  :D I have done this already but to get the right JSON from rotten tomatoes I need to include the search keyword in my url. The problem is that I don't know how to pass this keyword.

Comment: @ΕλένηΜάρκου: isn't the url parameter `url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q='+ filter +  '&page_limit=10&page=1&apikey=MyKey&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'` not working? The `q=filter` is used to filter the returned JSON

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggested.  The q parameter isn't null anymore but for some reason it takes the value 'function'. No matter what keyword I use I get the same results as if I had typed function. Although it is not working properly yet, it is still a progress so.. thank you !